# Spring API doesn't login and send infos (get&set) to React with JWT with same code

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jwt, lombok

The title is self explanatory, I have this API made in Spring, and after JWT implementation I can login, but the *gets* doesn't work anymore.

But if I comment the the **CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource()** and the Lombok annotation **@RequiredArgsConstructor** in SecurityConfig, the login stop to work, but all the *gets* work beautifully.

I'll post the class SecurityConfig, AuthorizationFilter and the AuthenticationFilter respectively for you guys try to see whats going wrong.

```
import org.alterdata.shopback.app.security.AuthenticationFilter;
import org.alterdata.shopback.app.security.AuthorizationFilter;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.config.http.SessionCreationPolicy;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter;

import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.web.cors.CorsConfiguration;
import org.springframework.web.cors.CorsConfigurationSource;
import org.springframework.web.cors.UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource;

import java.util.Arrays;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{


    @Autowired
    UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder;


    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        AuthenticationFilter authenticationFilter = new AuthenticationFilter(authenticationManagerBean());
        http.cors().and().csrf().disable();
        http.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/login").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/cadastrar/**").hasAnyAuthority("ADMIN")
        .antMatchers("/cadastro/**").hasAnyAuthority("ADMIN")
        .anyRequest().authenticated();
        http.addFilter(authenticationFilter);
        http.addFilterBefore(new AuthorizationFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }


    @Override
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(bCryptPasswordEncoder);
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager()throws Exception{
        return super.authenticationManager();
    }


    @Bean
    public CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
        configuration.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("http://localhost:3000"));
        configuration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE","OPTIONS", "HEAD"));
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
            return source;
        }
}
```

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Arrays;

import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import com.auth0.jwt.exceptions.JWTVerificationException;
import io.jsonwebtoken.JwtException;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.core.authority.SimpleGrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;
import org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter;

import com.auth0.jwt.JWT;
import com.auth0.jwt.algorithms.Algorithm;
import com.auth0.jwt.interfaces.DecodedJWT;
import com.auth0.jwt.interfaces.JWTVerifier;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

import net.bytebuddy.implementation.bind.annotation.IgnoreForBinding.Verifier;

import static org.springframework.util.MimeTypeUtils.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE;

@Slf4j
public class AuthorizationFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        if(request.getServletPath().equals("/login")) {
            filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
        }else {
            String authorizationHeader = request.getHeader(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION);
            if(authorizationHeader != null && authorizationHeader.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
                try {
                String token = authorizationHeader.substring("Bearer ".length());
                Algorithm algorithm = Algorithm.HMAC256("segredinho".getBytes());
                JWTVerifier jwtVerifier = JWT.require(algorithm).build();
                DecodedJWT decodedJWT = jwtVerifier.verify(token);
                String user = decodedJWT.getSubject();
                String [] roles = decodedJWT.getClaim("roles").asArray(String.class);
                Collection<SimpleGrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<>();
                Arrays.stream(roles).forEach(role ->{
                    authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role));
                });
                UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authenticationToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(user,null, authorities);
                SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authenticationToken);
                filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
                
            }catch(Exception e){
                    log.error("erro ao realizar o login! {}", e.getMessage());
                    response.setHeader("erro", e.getMessage());
                    response.setStatus(401);
                    Map<String, String> error = new HashMap<>();
                    error.put("mensagem de erro", e.getMessage());
                    response.setContentType(APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE);
                    new ObjectMapper().writeValue(response.getOutputStream(), error);
                }
            }else {
                filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
            }
            }
        }
    }
```

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.core.AuthenticationException;
import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter;

import com.auth0.jwt.JWT;
import com.auth0.jwt.algorithms.Algorithm;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.CrossOrigin;

import static org.springframework.http.MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE;


@CrossOrigin(origins = {"*"})
public class AuthenticationFilter extends UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter {

    private final AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;
    
    public AuthenticationFilter (AuthenticationManager authenticationManager) {
        this.authenticationManager = authenticationManager;
    }
    
    @Override
    public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws AuthenticationException {
        try{
            String nome = request.getParameter("nome");
            String senha = request.getParameter("senha");
            UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken uspsToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(nome, senha);
            //response.setHeader("teste", String.valueOf(uspsToken));
            return authenticationManager.authenticate(uspsToken);
        }catch (Exception e){
            throw new  RuntimeException();
        }

    }

//  @Override
//  public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
//          throws AuthenticationException {
//      try{
//  UserPasswordAuthRequest userPasswordAuthRequest = new ObjectMapper()
//              .readValue(request.getInputStream(), UserPasswordAuthRequest.class);
//
//          Authentication authentication = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
//                  userPasswordAuthRequest.getNome(),
//                  userPasswordAuthRequest.getSenha()
//          );
//          return authenticationManager.authenticate(authentication);
//      }catch (IOException e){
//          throw new  RuntimeException();
//      }
//  }

    @Override
    protected void successfulAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain chain,
            Authentication authResult) throws IOException, ServletException {
        User user = (User) authResult.getPrincipal();
        Algorithm algorithm = Algorithm.HMAC256("segredinho".getBytes());
        String tokenAcesso = JWT.create().withSubject(user.getUsername())
                .withExpiresAt(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + 10*60*1000*60))
                .withIssuer(request.getRequestURL()
                        .toString()).withClaim("roles", user.getAuthorities()
                                .stream().map(GrantedAuthority::getAuthority).collect(Collectors.toList()))
                .sign(algorithm);
        String tokenRefresh = JWT.create().withSubject(user.getUsername())
                .withExpiresAt(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + 10*60*1000*60))
                .withIssuer(request.getRequestURL()
                        .toString()).withClaim("roles", user.getAuthorities()
                                .stream().map(GrantedAuthority::getAuthority).collect(Collectors.toList()))
                .sign(algorithm);
        Map<String, String> tokens = new HashMap<>();
        tokens.put("tokenacesso", tokenAcesso);
        tokens.put("tokenrefresh", tokenRefresh);
        response.setContentType(APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE);
        new ObjectMapper().writeValue(response.getOutputStream(),tokens);
    }
    

    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First try to call your api with Postman, else i think you need to add authorization jwt header to every api request after you login.

```
    export default function authHeader() {
  const user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'));
  if (user && user.accessToken) {
    return { Authorization: 'Bearer ' + user.accessToken };
  } else {
    return {};
  }
}
```

and then call your api like this:

```
return axios.get(API_URL + 'user', { headers: authHeader() });
```

for more informations try to visit: https://www.bezkoder.com/react-jwt-auth/

Comment: On Postman works perfect, the problem is just when I go to react, the token works without the login/cors, but when I put the cors, gets stops

Answer (score 0):

I just fixed using this global cors

```
@Bean
    public CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", new CorsConfiguration().applyPermitDefaultValues());
        return source;
        }
```